# How to create a custom Alpine Linux ISO image with custom kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, iso, alpine-linux

I would like to make a custom Alpine Linux ISO image with a custom kernel based on [`linux-lts`](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/tree/master/main/linux-lts). I know how to make it separately (make kernel with `abuild checksum && abuild -rK` command; make ISO with `mkimage.sh`), but I don't know how to include my custom kernel package when making ISO image with `mkimage.sh` script.

In order to do that, I tried the following:

- Add `linux-lts-5.15.22-r0` inside `mkimg.${PROFILE}.sh` and `genapkovl-${PROFILE}.sh` this way:

  `mkimg.${PROFILE}.sh`:

  ```bsh
  apks="$apks
     linux-lts-5.15.22-r0
  "
  ```

  `genapkovl-${PROFILE}.sh`:

  ```bsh
  # Generate apk world
  mkdir -p "$tmp"/etc/apk
  makefile root:root 0644 "$tmp"/etc/apk/world <<EOF
  alpine-base
  linux-lts-5.15.22-r0
  EOF
  ```

  It doesn't work. Also, I tried different variants of these, like:

  1. `linux-lts`
  2. `linux-lts-5.15.22`
  3. `linux-lts-5.15.22-r0.apk`
  4. `/home/build/packages/main/x86_64/linux-lts-5.15.22-r0.apk`
- Run `mkimage.sh` with `--repository /home/build/packages/main` didn't work either.

My custom kernel package (`linux-lts-5.15.22-r0.apk`) located at `/home/build/packages/main/x86_64`.

Is there any way to include the custom kernel package when making an ISO image with `mkimage.sh`?

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Custom_Kernel
https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_make_a_custom_ISO_image_with_mkimage